MS Outlook Addin is repeatedly failing to make requests to the right host sever
When pushing out apps via O365 admin, it takes forever to replicate outwards. Microsoft will tell you that it can take 24-72 hours. While we were waiting to see if our fixes worked, one of the changes I made took almost 2 days propagate.
The outlook addin in question has static js assets that make network requests to our host server to process emails. The issue is these static assets don't seem to update correctly or at all when code changes are pushed which results in failed network requests to our host server due to a mangled url that has since been updated.
The host server itself is up to date and if you took the manifest file and uploaded(side-loaded) it manually to your destkop outlook, it would work fine. My POV on part of the problem here is Microsoft and how long they take to update cache.
Any tips and tricks to a better or faster dev cycle would be much appreciated.
Here is what has happened so far.

I removed the add-in from O365, waited a day until is was removed from the organization. That wokred overnight.

I added it back with updated manifest and waited overnight for it to show back up in outlook.

In our js assets we make network request via : “xhr.open("POST", "/api/scan.php", true);”  but this doesn't work because a different origin/domain is added to the beginning of the string.

We changed it to ("POST", HOST_SERVER + "/api/scan.php", true);. This did not fix the issue.


